# Trying to edit a txt file from a range of user inputs in python

Tags: python-2.7

me: I am very new to coding.

What i'm trying to do: Allow the user to change a txt files data. E.g. The name of a person, the email of a person, etc.

Problem: Code accepts my inputs however, it does not change the txt file.

Code i've made already. 
[click here for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xF73.png)

```
    L = open("players.txt","r+")

    edit_name = raw_input ("Enter the name of the person you wish to edit: ")
    for line in L:
            s = line.strip()
            strings = s.split(",")
            if edit_name == strings[0]:
                    print strings[:8]
                    print " \t 1 - Forename \n"
                    print " \t 2 - Surname \n"
                    print " \t 3 - Email Address \n"
                    print " \t 4 - Phone Number \n"
                    print " \t 5 - Division \n"
                    print " \t 6 - Points in the new division\n"
                    print " \t 7 - Old division\n"
                    print " \t 8 - Old points\n"

                    option = raw_input("Enter the number of what you would like to edit: ")
                    if option == "1":
                            updated_forename = raw_input ("New forename: ") 
                            strings[0] = updated_forename
                    elif option == "2":
                            updated_surname = raw_input ("New surname: ")
                            strings[1] = updated_surname
                    elif option == "3":
                            updated_email = raw_input("New email: ")
                            strings[2] = updated_email
                    elif option == "4":
                            updated_phone_number = raw_input("New phonenumber: ")
                            strings[3] = updated_phone_number
                    elif option == "5":
                            updated_division = raw_input("New division: ")
                            strings[4] = updated_division
                    elif option == "6":
                            updated_points_new_div = raw_input("New points in division: ")
                            strings[5] = updated_points_new_div
                    elif option == "7":
                            updated_olddivision = raw_input("Old divison: ")
                            strings[6] = updated_olddivision
                    elif option == "8":
                            updated_oldpoints = raw_input("Old Points: ")
                            strings[7] = updated_oldpoints
                    print "Updated information"
                    print strings[:8]
    L.close() #Closes the file to free us usage space.
```

Text file i'm wanting to edit.
[click here for text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBCmh.png)

Im guessing I need to basically save over the existing text file with the new data that has been entered. The question is how?

Any help would be appreciated.
p.s. First time posting so i cannot post pictures as i don't have 10 reputation. My apologies.

Comment: could you please add the code here? Especially the relevant parts.

Comment: You should be able to see the code ive done. Its in a link next to the sentence. Code ive made already.

Comment: Users are encouraged to copy the relevant parts of their code into the question itself, not an external link and certainly not a picture, so that other users can access it easier and to prevent link delay.

Comment: okay, i didnt know you could just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actully writing to the file:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Change "L.open" to write mode "w", use "L.write()" to write new data, this means you need to **rewrite the data you don't want to change** and construct and write new data where you wanted it to be modified.

Pseudo-code:

```
Open file
for line in file
    if(line.name == selectedname):
        write_row_edited(something)
    else:
        write_line_unedited()
close file
```

I took the time to insert the missing peudo-code

```
#we need to load file into memory, so we can edit it (rewrite it modified)
file = open("players.txt","r")
data = file.read()
file.close()

datalines = data.split("\n")

#now we have the file "line-by-line" in memory so we can edit it

edit_name = raw_input ("Enter the name of the person you wish to edit: ")

file = open("players.txt","w")
for line in datalines:
    s = line.strip()
    strings = s.split(",")
    if edit_name == strings[0]:
        print strings[:8]
        print " \t 1 - Forename \n"
        print " \t 2 - Surname \n"
        print " \t 3 - Email Address \n"
        print " \t 4 - Phone Number \n"
        print " \t 5 - Division \n"
        print " \t 6 - Points in the new division\n"
        print " \t 7 - Old division\n"
        print " \t 8 - Old points\n"

        option = raw_input("Enter the number of what you would like to edit: ")
        if option == "1":
                updated_forename = raw_input ("New forename: ") 
                strings[0] = updated_forename
        elif option == "2":
                updated_surname = raw_input ("New surname: ")
                strings[1] = updated_surname
        elif option == "3":
                updated_email = raw_input("New email: ")
                strings[2] = updated_email
        elif option == "4":
                updated_phone_number = raw_input("New phonenumber: ")
                strings[3] = updated_phone_number
        elif option == "5":
                updated_division = raw_input("New division: ")
                strings[4] = updated_division
        elif option == "6":
                updated_points_new_div = raw_input("New points in division: ")
                strings[5] = updated_points_new_div
        elif option == "7":
                updated_olddivision = raw_input("Old divison: ")
                strings[6] = updated_olddivision
        elif option == "8":
                updated_oldpoints = raw_input("Old Points: ")
                strings[7] = updated_oldpoints
        print "Updated information"
        print strings[:8]

        #merge string so we can write it back
        newline = ",".join(strings)
        file.write(newline+"\n")
    else:
        file.write(line+"\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: It's "pseudocode" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode so in a program way it does nothing, as it can't execute, for a programmer it is a way to say "this is how it should be done, rewrite to program specific code" and what it should do, is as I stated iterating over the file, checking if the line is the line that should be edited, if not just dump the line back to the file, if it was, edit the line and dump it back

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch!!!! This works great. Thank you for putting in the time to help a newbie out. Ive been trying this for 3 weeks.